# Dynamo Db Spatial Search with GeoHashing

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

We have a project for a mobile app where an user search for places based on the user position and the category they prefer ("fast food restaurants" for example). The client want to use Dynamo Db and we are trying hard to understand how to best model the data.
All queries will be based in two fields:

An string containing the geohashing value for a rounding box --> That our Hash primary key
An int containing the category type of the item --> Range Key

After reading the documentation we found out that the solution doesn't follow the recommendations of Amazon because the Hash Key will be repeated a lot and not will good use of parallel scanning, and the Range Key doesn't represent a range at all.

So we are kind of lost on how to proceed. Any thanks will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Amazon CloudSearch (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/geosearch.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon release a lib for geo hashing (only in Java)
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb.html